# proper installation of 5inch lcd on raspberry pi B+ running PWNPi

Tags: display, touchscreen

I received this morning my new 5 inch LCD for my Raspberry B+, I have got a PwnPI 3.0 version.

The LCD displays with a big black gap on the right side when connected for the first time.  I figured it's because I haven't set the drivers...

Before downloading from [Waveshare](http://www.waveshare.com) I tried editing the `/boot/config.txt` file, changing some parameters to see if anything changes to the display:

- Tried adding "hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0" : everything froze at boot, white screeen
- Tried changing HDMI modes, groups: everything froze again and again and again...

---

So I decided to go with the installation procedure from the Waveshare wiki for the [5 Inch screen](http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/5inch_HDMI_LCD#Resources):

- Downloaded [LCD-show-150602.tar.gz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2SuLGFxizpVWkc0SnAxUUlNRWs/view?usp=sharing) from resources.
- Extracted and untarred files.
- Ran setup script: `sudo ./LCD5-show`
- Rebooted

Got a white screen, with everything frozen

- Took the SDcard out and edited `config.txt` again: at the end 9 lines were added after the LCD installation, I commented them all out with `#` to see if this is the problem

Now: the RPi boots, but won't start the GUI...

Any suggestions how can I install the screen correctly so I get use of all the screen's width? I don't care for the touch/pen use, I just need to stretch the display width!

Comment: Although waveshare may claim you can use their driver with a different image, unless they provide source code for it it is unlikely to be true.   It will be more likely if you swap in the kernel and `/lib/modules/x.x.x` from their image, but that may lead to other problems.  In short, *caveat emptor*.

Comment: went to elinux.org/RPiconfig#Video_mode_options and found out the right settings, i needed to set hdmi_group=2 and hdmi_mode=14..that was all... so i guess it was worth the whole 15 euros..!!!....  in short, aut viam inveniam aut faciam

Comment: That was lucky.  If you have time please leave an answer of your own if possible (there may be a rep bar on that).