# Raspberry pi 2 touch screen is not full screen

Tags: pi-2, touchscreen, pitft, kali

I am trying to get my touch screen working on my raspberry pi 2.  I am currently running kali linux and I believe I have set up the touch screen properly.  I am getting a display but part of the screen is not being used and shows a fuzzy picture.  See the attached picture for clarification.  Anybody else experience this and know a fix?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlesx.jpg

Comment: You might have a look at this: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/40820/5538 <- Make sure to read all the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set up the screen wrong.

If this is an Adafruit PiTFT:

When running the helper script, use the option 35r instead of the 28*.

Edit: I experienced this as well, and after a few hours of frustration, I figured it out.

Comment: @Collin Your welcome. Wouldn't want you to be frustrated like I was.